# IIS7 401 custom error page not redirecting, it just returns a 401 response

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis-7, custom-errors

I have created a custom error page for an application proxy layer on IIS 7. The problem is it doesnt redirect when a 401 is raised.

I added it through IIS, and this is applicationHost.config snippet:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
  <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Login.aspx" 
  responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

The front end is Angular app, and at the minute i handle the 401 in the FE from the response and deal with it accordingly, but i want IIS to handle the 401s so other frontends done need to worry about it.

So what appears to be happening at the minute is:

```
client sends request to -> application proxy layer -> IIS 7.0 intercepts 
    request and raises 401  (ticket expired) -> 401 response returned
```

So why is IIS returning a 401 response back and not hooking into the custom httpErrors?

I have tried variations httpErrors but it just seems to be ignored.

thanks for any help

Comment: IIS custom errors can be bypassed (an ASP.NET example https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/01/Bypassing-IIS-Error-Messages-in-ASPNET), so in your case you need to dig further into Angular to see how what exactly is inside.

Comment: i saw that blog post too. and have been doing a bit more research into error handling on IIS. thats probably what i need to do. thank you